# More informative error message for handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have set up an nodejs/express application server with handlebars. Everything works fine. But if I do something wrong within the code, I get such an error message in the browser and the console:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/home/proj/myproject/views/content"
  at EventEmitter.render (/home/proj/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)
  at ServerResponse.render (/home/proj/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
  at /home/proj/myproject/app.js:61:7
  at Layer.handle_error (/home/proj/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
  at trim_prefix (/home/proj/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
  at /home/proj/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
  at Function.process_params (/home/proj/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
  at IncomingMessage.next (/home/proj/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
  at done (/home/proj/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:956:25)
  at EventEmitter.render (/home/proj/myproject/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:581:14)
```

It's okay that I get an error message. But a bad one. I want to have a more reasonable error message!

First: The error message on the console does not reflect what has been gone wrong. Finding the reason for an error is very difficult. With such a general error message. I assume some kind of error handler should be registered somewhere in the code. I am sorry, but as I am new to express and handlebars I do not know where. Can you help and give me some information?

Second: The web page should not contain such an error message. The error message in the console should address developers while the error message in the console should address end users. A more user friendly error message is required for the end user. No paths should be presented here. How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself after a few hours of research about handlebars and express. Unfortunately most information you find is pretty poor and does only cover very basic aspects of handlebars and express.

The issue I ran into has nothing to do with handlebars. Instead it is related to express: Error handling can be configured within express itself. See the express documentation for details.